# SQL JOIN on one field or the other

Tags: sql, sqlite

Trying to order a family by father's name or, if there is no father, then the mother's name where the names are in a separate "person" table, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT family.myid FROM family 
   JOIN person 
   ON family.father_id = person.myid OR
   family.mother_id = person.myid
   ORDER BY person.surname, 
            person.given_name;
```

In this version, the families without fathers end up unsorted at the bottom. Would like families without fathers to appear in the order by the mother's name. Sqlite SQL will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need a separate join for the fathers and the mothers:

```
select f.*
from family f left join
     person d
     on f.father_id = d.myid left join
     person m
     on f.mother_id = m.myid
order by (case when d.myid is null then m.surname else d.surname end),
         (case when d.myid is null then m.given_name else d.given_name end);
```

Because a value could be missing, this should be a `left join`.

Answer (score 2):

COALESCE should work

```
   ORDER BY COALESCE(NULLIF(b.surname, ''), c.surname),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(b.given_name, ''), c.given_name)
```